# MySQL select "n" rows and onButtonClick select next "n" rows

Tags: php, mysql

I hope that I have written title right.

My idea, what I want to achieve:

I have (Instagram based layout with posts(images)). On page load I want to select "n" rows (For example 50). After those 50 rows I want to show button (Load More). If I click this button I want to load next 50 rows. And so, for every 50 rows (post count may be in millions).

**I don't want to load all data and make them in pages**, because

1. I want to achieve this, to save internet data.
2. It takes long time to load all posts.

This is how I select data from mysql (At this moment):

```
SELECT * 
FROM fun_posts fp 
JOIN ( 
    SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) AS upvotes 
    FROM fun_post_upvotes 
    GROUP BY image_id 
    ORDER BY DATE(date) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) DESC, 
    count(*) DESC, 
    date DESC ) fpu 
ON ( fpu.image_id = fp.id )
```

Comment: Use the LIMIT function: LIMIT offset, length. LIMIT 0, 50 for the page load, first click - LIMIT 50,50, second click - LIMIT 100, 50... etc.

Comment: @OfirBaruch How I understand. For first posts I can just add this LIMIT function, but how about next posts and buttons? I have to make automatic button and button function generating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets consider you have query as per your requirement,

then following code will be help you,

```
SELECT * 
FROM fun_posts fp 
JOIN ( 
    SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) AS upvotes 
    FROM fun_post_upvotes 
    GROUP BY image_id 
    ORDER BY DATE(date) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) DESC, 
    count(*) DESC, 
    date DESC ) fpu 
ON ( fpu.image_id = fp.id )
limit START_ROW,EXPECTED_NO_OF_ROW

you required this in lazy loading so your variables should be change on each load, 
Example : Lets consider you want to show 50 rows then,
1st load : START_ROW = 0, EXPECTED_NO_OF_ROW = 50 
2nd load : START_ROW = 50, EXPECTED_NO_OF_ROW = 50 
3rd load : START_ROW = 100, EXPECTED_NO_OF_ROW = 50 so on....
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) which is done on the example page as:

> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

Since you want to make sure you're taking the sequential list, you want it inside your derived join table. Your limit will always be 50 (the number of posts that you want), and your offset will needed to be calculated as `50*(page-1)` so page 1 would be `LIMIT 0, 50`, page 2 is `LIMIT 50, 50...`

```
SELECT * 
FROM fun_posts fp 
JOIN ( 
    SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) AS upvotes 
    FROM fun_post_upvotes 
    GROUP BY image_id 
    ORDER BY DATE(date) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) DESC, 
    count(*) DESC, 
    date DESC
    LIMIT x, 50 ) fpu -- Where is the offset that is calculated 
ON ( fpu.image_id = fp.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass dynamic Offset and limit from php to mysql

first set`limit = 50;`

Then first set `offset = 0;` Than every time add your `offset` in `limit` like

```
offset = offset + limit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit to the server a param called "page" or something like and then use OFFSET and LIMIT.

Example of client:

```
...
    <a href="url?page=1">Page 1</a>
    <a href="url?page=2">Page 2</a>
...
```

Example of server script:

```
<?php
$serverPagination = 50; // you can modify the number of rows per page
$serverPage = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] - 1 : 0; // for offset
$offset = $pagination * $serverPage;

$sql = "
SELECT * 
FROM fun_posts fp 
JOIN ( 
    SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) AS upvotes 
    FROM fun_post_upvotes 
    GROUP BY image_id 
    ORDER BY DATE(date) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) DESC, 
    count(*) DESC, 
    date DESC ) fpu 
ON ( fpu.image_id = fp.id ) LIMIT {$serverPagination} OFFSET {$offset}";

// excution of query
?>
```